# How to Test conditional independence between random variables using available samples?

Tags: matlab, bayesian, random, bayesian-networks

How can I test for the independence between two random variable given another one(i.e. whether P(A|C)=P(A|C,B) or not?) using available samples. in other words, I just have 1000 samplesf for 3 random variables generated by bntoolbox on Matlab and now I wanna test for CI between arbitrary random variables.
I've read something about Fisher's method but honestly don't understand it.

Thanks is advance.